# Maven and Android Testing/Build Life-Cycle

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, android-testing, intellij-15

​
I'm using Intellij 15 and have an app whose top-level module maven module that is setup as an aggregator, i.e. pom.

Inside of that I created a plain old java module using maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1.
I got junit working the way i need it to and the maven life-cycle runs complete with no issues. I'm sure this is setup correctly.

I created a second module using de.akquinet.android.archetypes.android-quickstart. This builds properly, as well it picks up the dependency on the POJ library (the first module) correctly. The maven life-cycle is also successful.

however... the maven 'test' goal uses surefire which seems to only run ordinary POJ junit out of the box.

I tried following the instructions on the Jetbrains site for setting up Android testing - create an Android Test Module and point it at the Android App module. But this did not create the "stub" test for MainActivity class...

it hasn't been very straightforward...

So, I can't do Android unit testing with my Android module created from Android quickstart archetype. At least not out of the box...

1. Was it a mistake to create the Android module using the maven Android quickstart?
2. I didn't want to mix gradle and maven and have to figure out how to setup the poj library dependency but I'm wondering if that is the way to to this.

Another aspect of my query regards the whole matter of using maven to manage an Android project at all.

3. My assumption is that using gradle in Intellij will work as automagically well as it does using Android Studio.
4. The maven Android support doesn't seem to be very bleeding edge. Is it just legacy, or have I simply not yet found the correct door?
5. Finally, Android Studio has some build options such as flavors, build varients, etc., if I wind up using gradle to manage the Android module, will I have all the same options?
6. I really prefer the Intellij Ultra product over the Android Studio version. Are there any compelling reasons to use Android Studio over Intellij for Android design?

Thanks in advance!